# Drawing object lines in the Tiled map editor

Tags: java, libgdx, tiled

Suppose I have this picture:

[image]

I have a map like this created in Tiled already. I would like to draw collision lines (the green ones in the picture) without having to make it a polygon. As far as I know, Tiled does not support drawing a line as a collision object, so I would appreciate ideas on how to make this work.

I also tried drawing a quadrilateral and calculating the diagonal in code (LibGDX), but that's a bit clunky and can go wrong easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tiled *does* support drawing lines as collision objects. To do this, you should just [not close the polygon](https://doc.mapeditor.org/en/latest/manual/objects/#polylines) (right-click once you're done with the polyline).

In the past these have been separate tools, but in Tiled 1.2 they have been unified into a single tool. Probably the UI needs to be more clear that the tool can be used to create both polygons and polylines.